# O que significa o termo "OOO" na seguinte frase? "Estarei OOO de 6 de Junho a 13 de Junho"

Tags: significado, expressões, frases

O que significa o termo "OOO" na seguinte frase?  "Estarei OOO de 6 de Junho a 13 de Junho" Recebi-a via email

Comment: Eu suporia que significa que a pessoa não estará disponível nesse período. Que meios de comunicação ela costuma usar? Pois poderia ser referência a algum símbolo de algum programa usado para denotar ausência (talvez o MS Teams).

Comment: Recebi via email  no Outlook

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em inglês significa "out of [the] office", quer dizer, "fora do escritório". Imagino que, apesar do resto da frase ser em português, este acrónimo foi emprestado do inglês.

Comment: Ah, não conhecia. Muito provável mesmo.